# Apache NiFi - "Execution" Option

Tags: apache-nifi

Can someone tell me what is the use of "Execution" option in Apache NiFi ?

This option is available for most of the processors and there are 2 values  we can choose currently - Primary Node & All Cluster.

One use case I can think of is - reading data from Kafka and you want to load balance the read.

May be I got confused with the use of this option as it is provided for most of the processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary Node Only is for the case where a source processor should only execute on one node. For example, if you had a GetSFTP processor at the start of your flow in a 3 node cluster, you wouldn't want this to run on all 3 nodes because they would all get the same files.

The most common use of primary node only is probably the List + Fetch pattern. The flow starts with a List processor like ListHDFS which runs on Primary Node Only, followed by a load balanced connection to distributed the listings to all nodes, connected to FetchHDFS running on all nodes.

https://pierrevillard.com/2018/10/29/nifi-1-8-revolutionizing-the-list-fetch-pattern-and-more/

Processors that are not the first processor in the flow should never really be set to primary node only, even though the application allows it. This can probably be improved.

Comment: Any idea why there is only 2 options are provided for Execution ? Why something like "only on this many nodes" are NOT provided ? Let's say my cluster has 4 machines, and if I wanted my Kafka consumer to work on only 2 nodes there is no way to do that.

Comment: We could eventually implement node groups, but it was more complicated and often not necessary. In most cases you want everything running on all nodes, and then a few special cases you need one node only.

Comment: Yeah, it might be useful for some scenarios like Kafka consumer - because if my topic is having 2 partitions only, then there is no point in having the consumer be deployed in 4 nodes..

Comment: Sure, but its not going to hurt anything to run on all nodes because the consumer will only consume on 2 of your 4 nodes, and the other 2 will just do nothing.

Comment: It would be the second picture here under ConsumeKafka where theres 3 NiFi nodes and 2 partitions - https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/09/15/apache-nifi-and-apache-kafka

Comment: Ya.agree..The reason why I asked the question is - I can see this option is available for most processors; even for QueryDatabaseTable..may be it's good to restrict it to processors where it is useful ..just to avoid confusion.